# How are alert triggered pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, alerts, pine-script-v4

I have little experience programming.

I have script that recognises a doji candle and changes the colour to yellow.

First can you write a script that create a alert fi=unction for a colour change?

Secondly how do you create a alert to change a colour of a candle what function is chosen  from the conditions pull down menu that starts from
crossing .... and ends with .... moving % down ?

Could I chose for example when the candle is recognised as a doji
1.Moving up %  in 1 bar OR
2. Moving up .20 in 2 bars?

to set the alert?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own code for that.

You probably have something like this in your code:

```
barcolor(cond ? color.yellow : na)
```

Use that condition that changes the color to yellow to trigger your alerts.

```
fire_alert = not cond[1] and cond  // Only trigger the alert once
alertcondition(fire_alert, "Color changed", "Color changed to yellow")
```

Comment: Yes I have this - barcolor(abs(open - close) <= (high - low) * Precision ? yellow : na)

Comment: How does this fire alert function link to the conditions when you use the create alert function in the chart window?

Comment: got this error - 
line 9: root_alert_cond expression of alert_0 has invalid type: const__string expected series__bool

Comment: Added this line to the code - alertcondition("Doji signals", "Color changed", "Color changed to yellow")